# Regular expression to find alphanumeric IDs

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to extract the IDs from this string, i.e. `SS123456`, `87654321`, `AAA12345`:

```
["EMP_ID eq 'SS123456","EMP_ID eq '87654321","EMP_ID eq 'AAA12345"]
```

How can I do this with a regular expression?

Comment: have you tried any thing?

Comment: Is there supposed to be a closing single quote after each ID, e.g. `"EMP_ID eq 'AAA12345'"`?

Comment: ["EMP_ID eq 'SS123456'","EMP_ID eq '87654321'","EMP_ID eq 'AAA12345'"]

Comment: yes,there is closing single quote after the each ID.

Answer (score 1):

If the strings are always in the same form you don't need a regular expression - you could split on the common `eq '`:

```
var ids = data.map(function(entry) {
  return entry.split("eq '")[1]
})
```

Your data looks a little strange in that the IDs have an opening, but not closing single quote. If they are meant to have quotes around the ID, a simple regular expression will work:

```
var dataWithQuotes = ["EMP_ID eq 'SS123456'","EMP_ID eq '87654321'","EMP_ID eq 'AAA12345'"]
var ids = dataWithQuotes.map(function(entry) {
  return entry.match(/'(\w+)'/)[1]
})
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're matching the tokens in the array that are within the single quote area and the closing quote is optional:

```
["EMP_ID eq 'SS123456","EMP_ID eq '87654321","EMP_ID eq 'AAA12345"].map(function(input){
   var match = input.match(/'(.+)'?/);
   return (match[1]);
});
```